# Abstract constructor type in TypeScript

Tags: constructor, typescript, abstract-class

The type signature for a non-abstract class (non-abstract constructor function) in TypeScript is the following:

```
declare type ConstructorFunction = new (...args: any[]) => any;
```

This is also called a *newable* type. However, I need a type signature for an *abstract* class (abstract constructor function). I understand it can be defined as having the type `Function`, but that is *way* too broad. Isn't there a more precise alternative?

---

**Edit:**

To clarify what I mean, the following little snippet demonstrates the difference between an abstract constructor and a non-abstract constructor:

```
declare type ConstructorFunction = new (...args: any[]) => any;

abstract class Utilities {
    ...
}

var UtilityClass: ConstructorFunction = Utilities; // Error.
```

> Type 'typeof Utilities' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any[]) => any'.
>
> > Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Maybe provide more code? Why is there a difference in this case between abstract and non-abstract classes? The ctor is never abstract.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I appreciate your help. I've edited a [mcve] into the question to demonstrate the problem. Basically, I need to pass a class as an argument. The type `ConstructorFunction` works for non-abstract classes, but not for abstract ones.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Was just struggling with a similar problem myself, and this seems to work for me:

```
type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T }
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what is needed.
@cheez - This describes a Function with a prototype - so instead of requiring that the type defines a constructor, this defines that it defines the prototype. Which is what an abstract class is - no constructor, just the prototype.

Comment: Could you please share an example of this making a class with an abstract constructor.  Perhaps including extending the class?

Comment: @Knagis could one of you please elaborate on this answer.  I'd really like to be able to use it, but the way it's shown above is not a complete enough answer for me to understand.

Comment: Above queries answered in follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349758/how-does-type-constructort-function-prototype-t-apply-to-abstract-c/52350147#52350147

Answer (score 36):

As of TypeScript 4.2, you can use an [abstract constructor type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures):

```js
abstract class Utilities {
    abstract doSomething(): void;
}

type ConstructorFunction = abstract new (...args: any[]) => any;
var UtilityClass: ConstructorFunction = Utilities; // ok!
```

Comment: This is now the best answer, imo.

Comment: nice, but does not work with protected constructors in typescript 4.9.4: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgqhAlsnuAphgN4BQClCokM8CAJgPYDKTAtoRABY4B2AcwAUASgBcCAG5McDANxkAvmTIQAngAdCCAMJM+tAK7wmUAGKG+8HPoQBeauGhxEfQgHcEQgHS-gUATAJYD41AG0AXRF7AD5qUIVJfyxcfHUdVHQJPQNoYwhTCytcWwdsPAIcYjkEAHpahCYAawBCFRpnehQ0DDMmJgRyKgQNKCYIQnhCBiR9IxMoUUHlZVqAKjWKNYR1LTBYKBwNRAAWbwBObxOthAAVTW0Acl3CJgAzBD6mR4QcDD5xtR0DgBHxQMhtAUdg8EI8cvMCuZLNZ9I9vDdKDoQgDED0QXxqLDRuNJhMGD9YHM8gtoVodgNgETDCB8LAKVSoPlTLTCOiEGtamRKbkEG9+jpEdkOVykcUbASHF8FEA)

Comment: @TmTron Indeed, at the moment you can't have a visibility modifier on a `new()` type. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30991

Answer (score 4):

The whole point with abstract classes (in OO in general) is that you can not instantiate them, you need a concrete non-abstract implementation.

I assume that you want to have different implementations to that abstract class and want to be able to receive one of those implementations (as a parameter or something of the likes).
If that's the case, then maybe this might solve your problem:

```
declare type ConstructorFunction<T extends Utilities> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

abstract class Utilities { }

class MyUtilities extends Utilities { }

var UtilityClass: ConstructorFunction<MyUtilities> = MyUtilities;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I _need_ to pass an abstract class as an argument, which is possible if the parameter type is `any` or `Function`. However, these types allow objects other than abstract classes to be passed as well, hence my need for a type definition especially for abstract classes.

Comment: @JohnWhite Why do you need to pass an abstract class? That's a weird scenario

Comment: Yeah, it is. It's for a custom serialization/deserialization engine where it's possible to annotate properties with decorators. Member polymorhpism is supported, and therefore an abstract class can be specified for a property type, which is then passed into a metadata structure. Runtime type checks are in place currently, but it would be significantly better with type-safety.

Comment: @JohnWhite if I get you right then you only need that abstract class to get metadata from it. If that's the case then just get it as `any` because I don't see the benefits of having the class type.  Unless I'm missing something, if that's the case then you probably should explain the scenario better to get real help.

Comment: I know this is old but I'm running into the same issue, I'm using polymorphism to store the child classes of a certain class in a map, but can't instantiate them because the parent is marked as abstract. I'd like type-safety on the constructor arguments as the spec is still in flux but can't have it because the compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem. I guess, an essence of abstract class constructor signature is an *absense* of `new ( ... ) : X` thingy in its declaration. That's why it can be declared explicitly.

However. You can do this, and it will compile.

```
var UtilityClass: typeof Utilities  = Utilities;
```

`typeof Something` is a nice way to reference constructor types, however, it cannot be extended.

And in any case you can do thing like this:

```
var UtilityClass: ConstructorFunction = <any> Utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution:

```
type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T }
```

won't allow you to create instances of this type using *new* keyword.

There's another simple solution:

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => AbstractClass
```

*((Where `AbstractClass` is a name of your AbstractClass))*

Comment: And what is the `AbstractClass` in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TehauCave's answer, which was my starting point, I could figure out a way to define a type that also cares about parameter types.

```
export type Constructor<T, TArgs extends any[] = any> = Function & {
    prototype: T,
    apply: (this: any, args: TArgs) => void
};
```

The above type can be used either

- regardless of parameter types:

  ```
  Constructor<YourAbstractClass>
  ```

or

- restricting parameter types:

  ```
  Constructor<YourAbstractClass, [number, string, boolean]>
  ```

---

Using the `Constructor` type, it is also possible to infer the parameter types of a given constructor:

```
type ConstructorParameters<T extends Constructor<any>> = T extends Constructor<any, infer TParams> ? TParams : never;
```

and then,

```
ConstructorParameters<YourAbstractClass> // e.g., [number, string, boolean]
```