# custom generic instanceof function

Tags: typescript

I am performing an `instanceof` check in `*ngIf`.

```
 <span *ngFor="let element of elements"> 
   <app-text *ngIf="element instanceof BlueElement"></app-text>
 </span>
```

Unfortunately, `instanceof` cannot be used, because it is defined by javascript.

Therefore I created my own `instanceOf` method:

```
  instanceOf<T,C>(value:T,clss:C){
    if (value instanceof C){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I am getting an error; `C is only defined as a type, but is being used as a value here.`

How should I rewrite the generic `instanceOf()` function?

Comment: you'd need `value instanceof clss`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) on a constructor value.

That means it must be a *constructor* value as opposed to just any old object.  TypeScript only requires the `constructor` property of a class to be a `Function`, so at the very least you need to specify that `C extends Function`.  If you want to be safer, restrict `C` to actual constructor functions whose singatures are like `new(...args: any[])=>any`.

It also means it must be a constructor *value* as opposed to its *type*.  The value is `clss`, and its type is `C`.  As pointed out by [@vu1p3n0x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/vu1p3n0x), you should write`instanceof clss`.  You can't write `instanceof C`, since `C` is just a type and it doesn't even exist at runtime.

Putting that together:

```
function instanceOf<T, C extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(value: T, clss: C): boolean {
  return value instanceof clss;
}
```

As an aside, note that in JavaScript `value instanceof clss` evaluates either `true` or `false`.  So you can just return it instead of checking it with `if`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: And to use this for classes with abstract members (a base class type), add `abstract` to the constructor signature `C extends abstract new ...`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229348/3246449   Also in my case it seemed to work better (?) when the c'tor signature has `=> C` instead of `=> any`.