# How does `type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T }` apply to Abstract constructor types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor, abstract-class

There is this Q&A about Abstract constructor types in TypeScript, which is a question I would like to know the answer to:

[Abstract constructor type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886082/abstract-constructor-type-in-typescript)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer is little more that an unexplained one-liner: `type Constructor<T> = Function & { prototype: T }`

It appears that this answer is good enough for the asker, it is the accepted answer, but I'm unable to understand how the answer applies to the question.

I've tried asking in the comments, and I've tried asking someone in chat to explain the answer, but to no avail.  Also, I recognize that this is only barely a different question from that one, but this is still a unique question about code.

How can I use a type of `Function & { prototype: T }` to emulate an abstract class of known constructor type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can verify in the playground that an abstract class `C` is assignable to `Constructor<C>`.  Is there something further you are trying to do with the type `Constructor<C>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Using_prototypes_in_JavaScript), all functions have a special property called `prototype`.  If you use a function as a constructor (by calling it with `new`), the constructed instance will have that as its prototype.  This is how classes worked in JavaScript before ES2015:

```
// ES5-flavored class 
function Foo() { } // a normal function 
Foo.prototype.prop = 0; // adding a property to Foo.prototype
var f = new Foo(); // using Foo as a constructor
f.prop; // the instance inherits the added property
```

ES2015 introduced the `class` syntax, which behaves the same way under the hood... and so constructor objects still have a `prototype` property from which constructed instances inherit.

```
// ES2015-flavored class
class Foo { } // explicitly a class
Foo.prototype.prop = 0; // adding a property to Foo.prototype
const f = new Foo(); // using Foo as a constructor
f.prop; // the instance inherits the added property
```

TypeScript models this by declaring that the `Function` interface, which all functions implement, has a [`prototype` property of type `any`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L298).  Furthermore, when the `class` syntax is used, the constructor is still seen as a `Function`, and the `prototype` property of the [constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.3/doc/spec.md#825-constructor-function-types) is narrowed from `any` to the same type as the constructed class instance:

```
// TypeScript code
class Foo { 
  prop!: number;  // Foo has a prop
} 
Foo.prototype; // inspects as type Foo
Foo.prototype.prop = 0; // so this works
const f = new Foo(); // inspects as type Foo
f.prop; // inspects as type number
```

Even `abstract` classes in TypeScript have a `prototype` property whose type is the same as the instance type.  So while you can't call `new` on an abstract class constructor, or match it to a newable type like `new() => any`, you can still talk about its `prototype`:

```
// more TS code
abstract class Bar {
  abstract prop: number;
}
Bar.prototype; // inspects as type Bar
Bar.prototype.prop = 0; // so this works
const b = new Bar(); // whoops can't do this though
```

All this means that in TypeScript a possibly-abstract class constructor is (a subtype of) a `Function` whose `prototype` property is the instance type for the constructor.  Thus, you can say that

```
type PossiblyAbstractConstructor<T> = Function & {prototype: T};
```

using the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) operator to combine `Function` and "object with a `prototype` property of type `T`"...

or similarly

```
interface PossiblyAbstractConstructor<T> extends Function {
  prototype: T;
}
```

using [interface extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces) to achieve the same effect...

and you know that the following is valid:

```
const fooConstructor: PossiblyAbstractConstructor<Foo> = Foo;
const barConstructor: PossiblyAbstractConstructor<Bar> = Bar;
```

That should explain how the original question's answer is applicable.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think you've very much helped me find the root of my confusion.  I've been thinking that this technique would help me create some `abstract class ConstructorTakesStringAsOnlyArgument` in order to have a group of extending classes of known constructor arguments.  It seems that this technique is for creating an abstract constructor of unknown argument types.  Is this correct?

Comment: It’s true that this technique does not give you any handle on the argument types of the constructor... but abstract classes *don’t have* constructor arguments, right?

Comment: No, not really.  The notion of an abstract constructor is still useful though.  I asked another question about it here if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350788/is-it-possible-to-enforce-constructor-parameter-types-with-extends-or-impleme/52351413#52351413

Comment: Yeah I guess you can specify constructor parameters for an abstract class; I don’t know of any way to programmatically extract those parameter types, unfortunately.