# Infer arguments for abstract class in typescript

Tags: typescript, arguments, abstract-class, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get the arguments for typescript classes and functions.

```
export type CtorArgs<TBase> = TBase extends new (...args: infer TArgs) => infer Impl ? TArgs : never;
export type AbsCtorArgs<TBase> = TBase extends {constructor: (...args: infer TArgs) => infer Impl} ? TArgs : never;
export type FuncArgs<TBase> = TBase extends (...args: infer TArgs) => infer Impl ? TArgs : never;

function RegularFunction(a:string,b:number){}
class RegularClass{
    constructor(a:string,b:number){}
}    
abstract class AbstractClass{
    constructor(a:string,b:number){}
}


type thing = [
    CtorArgs<typeof RegularClass>,
    FuncArgs<typeof RegularFunction>,
    AbsCtorArgs<typeof AbstractClass>,
    CtorArgs<typeof AbstractClass>,
    FuncArgs<typeof AbstractClass>
];
```

But for some reason abstract classes don't return arguments of their constructors.
[image: Returns only never]
I suspect this is because the `new` keyword [isn't available on abstract classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10551). Does anybody know how to get those arguments which do actually exist for an abstract class constructor?

And no, this isn't about instantiating a abstract classes, this is about dependency injection to a class that inherits from an abstract class and the arguments to that class. [See here](https://github.com/aurelia/dependency-injection/pull/182#issuecomment-524662589)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abstract constructor type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886082/abstract-constructor-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate,  I want to know this too. This is specifically about retrieving the parameters for the constructor from an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to infer parameters of `abstract` class. You just need to add `abstract` keyword before `new`.

See example:

```js
abstract class AbstractClass {
    constructor(a: string, b: number) { }
}
export type InferAbstract<T> = T extends abstract new (...args: infer Args) => infer _ ? Args : never;

type Result = InferAbstract<typeof AbstractClass> // [a: string, b: number]
```

But you don't even need to use some custom utility types. You can use built it `[ConstructorParameters][1]` which was introduced in TS 3.1

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype